# php carbon check if now is between two times (10pm-8am)

Tags: php, php-carbon

```
$start = '22:00:00';
$end = '08:00:00';
$now = Carbon::now('UTC');
```

How can I check if the time of $now is within the timerange?

Comment: If $start and $end are  within the same day, $now is not within the range.

Answer (score 46):

There are several ways to achieve that by using Carbon. One of the easiest ways is using `createFromTimeString` and `between` methods:

```php
$now = Carbon::now();

$start = Carbon::createFromTimeString('22:00');
$end = Carbon::createFromTimeString('08:00')->addDay();

if ($now->between($start, $end)) {
    // ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
}
```

Comment: For everyone, who looks of this. Please keep in mind the the method `createFromTimeString` will always return the current date from an clock like time-input.

This really can become to an issue, when you pass midnight. Then in this example, suddenly the next day and the day after tomorrow will become the target date and times.

So, you've to put a date-string into the method-parameter and update/store it via database or file.

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
  $time = Carbon::now();
  $morning = Carbon::create($time->year, $time->month, $time->day, 8, 0, 0); //set time to 08:00
  $evening = Carbon::create($time->year, $time->month, $time->day, 18, 0, 0); //set time to 18:00
  if($time->between($morning, $evening, true)) {
    //current time is between morning and evening
  } else {
    //current time is earlier than morning or later than evening
  }
```

The `true` in `$time->between($morning, $evening, true)` checks whether the `$time` is between and including `$morning` and `$evening`. If you write `false` instead it checks just if it is between the two times but not including.

Actually, you could leave `true` away because it is set by default and not needed.

Check [here](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-comparison) for more information on how to compare dates and times with Carbon.

Answer (score 8):

```
$start = '22:00:00';
$end   = '08:00:00';
$now   = Carbon::now('UTC');
$time  = $now->format('H:i:s');

if ($time >= $start && $time <= $end) {
    ...
}
```

Should do it, but doesn't take date into consideration

Comment: Your OR logic is wrong. It should be AND. If now is 13:00:00 and range is 12:00:00 to 12:45:00, then your solution would answer yes because $time is actually >= $start.

Comment: If you consider the time as "23:00:00", your logic is going to be wrong.

Comment: @Hamidreza care to explain? "23:00:00" is greater than the start time of "22:00:00", so the logic checks out to me

Answer (score 4):

You can reverse check algorithm.

```php
<?php
$pushChannel = "general";

$now = Carbon::now();

$start = Carbon::createFromTime(8, 0);
$end = Carbon::createFromTime(22, 0);

if (!$now->between($start, $end)) {
     $pushChannel = "silent";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$restrictStartTime = Carbon::createFromTime(22, 0, 0);  //carbon inbuild function which will create todays date with the given time
$restrictEndTime = Carbon::createFromTime(8, 0, 0)->addDays(1); //this will create tomorrows date with the given time
$now = Carbon::now();

if($now->gt($restrictStartTime) && $now->lt($restrictEndTime)) {
 .....
 }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: I suggest you to explain how to automatically convert the `$start = '22:00:00';` bit into what you proposed `$restrictStartTime = Carbon::createFromTime(22, 0, 0);`

Answer (score 1):

Please Try below code,

```
$start = '22:00:00';
$end = '08:00:00';
$now = Carbon::now('UTC');

$nowTime = $now->hour.':'.$now->minute.':'.$now->second;

if(strtotime($nowTime) > strtotime($start) && strtotime($nowTime) < strtotime($end) ) {
    echo 'YES';
} else {
    echo 'NO';
}
```

Comment: Does not solve the date range problem (i.e. $now > $start && $now < $end is not sufficient)

Comment: Actually do you want to range time?  isn't it ? Please try answer code again. if it is not solve describe me.

Answer (score 1):

What Chris is trying to point out is if the endtime crosses over midnight then you must account for that.

This is not the cleanest way to do it but here is a method that seems to work.

```
private function isNowBetweenTimes($timezone, $startDateTime, $endDateTime) {
    $curTimeLocal = Carbon::now($timezone);
    $startTime = $curTimeLocal->copy();
    $startTime->hour = $startDateTime->hour;
    $startTime->minute = $startDateTime->minute;
    $endTime = $curTimeLocal->copy();
    $endTime->hour = $endDateTime->hour;
    $endTime->minute = $endDateTime->minute;
    if ($endTime->lessThan($startTime))
        $endTime->addDay();

    return ($curTimeLocal->isBetween($startTime, $endTime));
}
```

This example only cares about the hour and minutes and not the seconds but you can easily copy that as well. The key to this is comparing start and end time before comparing them to the current time and add a day to end time if end time is less than start time.

Answer (score 1):

For complete solution which supports all start and end time range you can use bitwise ***XOR***.

```
/*
 * must using hours in 24 hours format e.g. set 0 for 12 pm, 6 for 6 am and 13 for 1 pm
 */
private $startTime = '0';
private $endTime = '6';
    

$currentHour = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->hour;
$start = $this->startTime > $this->endTime ? !($this->startTime <= $currentHour) : $this->startTime <= $currentHour;
$end = $currentHour < $this->endTime;


if (!($start ^ $end)) {
  //Do stuff here if you want exactly between start and end time
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the midnight plays a vital role in time duration. We can find `now()` being the given time range as follows:

```
$now = Carbon::now();
$start = Carbon::createFromTime('22', '00');
$end = Carbon::createFromTime('08', '00');

if ($start->gt($end)) {
    if ($now->gte($start)) {
        $end->addDay();
    } elseif ($now->lte($end)) {
        $start->subDay();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

return $now->between($start, $end);
```

Comment: Very nice and neat , thank you

Answer (score 1):

an updated version of  @AliN11's answer taking into account ranges accross two days or in the same day

```
$now = now();

$start = Carbon::createFromTimeString('22:00');
$end = Carbon::createFromTimeString('08:00');
if ($start > $end) {
    $end = $end->addDay();
}
if ($now->between($start, $end)||$now->addDay()->between($start, $end)) {
   //add statements
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$start = 22; //Eg. start hour
$end = 08;  //Eg. end hour
$now = Carbon::now('UTC');

if( $start < $now->hour && $now->hour < $end){
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: That's not valid php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$now = date("H");

if ($now < "20") {
    echo "Have a good day!";
}
```

Comment: Does not solve the date range problem (i.e. $now > $start && $now < $end is not sufficient)

Answer (score 0):

@AliN11's (currently top) answer is good, but doesn't work as one would immediately expect, after midnight it just breaks, as raised in the comments by @Sasha

The solution is to reverse the logic, and check if the time is *not* between the inverse hours.

Here is an alternative that works as one would expect:

```
    $now = Carbon::now();
    $start = Carbon::createFromTimeString('08:00');
    $end = Carbon::createFromTimeString('22:00');

    if (! $now->between($start, $end)) {
        // We're all good
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an initial value to check the time interval you can initiate it with Carbon's **copy()** method and set the hours and minutes with **setHours()** and **setMinutes()**. After that, just use the regular **between()**.

For example, checking if "2022-01-28 19:00" is >= 07:00 and < 19:00.

```
$fromRequest = "2022-01-28 19:00";
$from = Carbon::parse($fromRequest);
$start = $from->copy()->setHours(7)->setMinutes(0);
$end = $from->copy()->setHours(18)->setMinutes(59);
$this->isDaytime = $from->between($start, $end); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel and PHP using carbon that time between used like this

```
$startDate = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i a', '08:00 AM');
$endDate = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i a', '07:00 PM');
$check = Carbon::now()->between($startDate, $endDate, true);
if($check){
    dd('In Between');
}else{
    dd('In Not Between');
}
```