# Unable to check time between two times after midnight with Carbon?

Tags: php, laravel, time, php-carbon

I was trying to check if the time exist between 2 times. I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59568382/7290043).

```
$now = Carbon::now(); 

$start = Carbon::createFromTimeString('08:00');
$end = Carbon::createFromTimeString('20:00');

if ($now->between($start, $end)) {
    // ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
}
```

But the problem that if `$end` time is after midnight i.e `$start = '20:00'` and $end tomorrow at `$end = '08:00'` and `$now = '06:00'`, it says `""` but it should be `"1"`, right?

```
$time= Carbon::createFromTimeString('06:00'); 
$start = Carbon::createFromTimeString('20:00');
$end = Carbon::createFromTimeString('08:00');

$time->between($start, $end); // return ""
```

I don't want to pass dates with the `$start` and `$end` times, what should I do?

Comment: It won't work without dates, or something that can act as dates. It's the only way you can indicate that a certain time is on the next day.

Comment: You could also add extra restrictions, for instance: 1. The `$end` date will always be after the `$start` date, and 2. `$start` and `$end` will never be further than 24 hours apart. In that case, if `$end` comes before `$start` you know it is on the next day.

Comment: How about `if ($end < $start) { $start = $start->addDay(); }` to cover the cases where e.g. end is `08:00` and start is `20:00` which (as you say) implies that you mean 20:00 today till 08:00 tomorrow?

Comment: _"and $end tomorrow at $end = '08:00'"_ - your forgot to actually implement "tomorrow" in any way. `Carbon::createFromTimeString('08:00')` - based on what should Carbon treat this as a "tomorrow time" rather than a "today time" ...?

Comment: @CBroe Yes exactly. but how to implement `tomorrow` in above case?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see much point in working with any datetime library, if your input times are in `hh:mm` format already - because that is perfectly comparable using string comparison.

If start < end, then simply check if the target time is between those two; if not, then check whether it is greater(/equal) than start, *or* smaller (/equal) than end:

```
function is_time_between($start, $end, $time) {
    if ($start < $end) {
        return $start <= $time && $time <= $end;
    } else {
        return $time >= $start || $time <= $end;
    }
    
    // or as a one-liner:
    // return $start < $end ? $start <= $time && $time <= $end : $time >= $start || $time <= $end;
}

var_dump(
    is_time_between('08:00', '20:00', '13:27'),
    is_time_between('08:00', '20:00', '23:27'),
    is_time_between('20:00', '08:00', '03:27'),
    is_time_between('20:00', '08:00', '23:27'),
    is_time_between('20:00', '08:00', '08:27'),
    is_time_between('20:00', '08:00', '16:27'),
);
```

Results:

```
bool(true)
bool(false)
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(false)
bool(false)
```

https://3v4l.org/GtPiQ